# Get the key and value of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to get the 'key' of ng-repeat in scope.$watch

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, contents_extended_data) in moderation.contents">
   <img src="" id='target_photo_[[contents_extended_data.reference]]'>
</div>

// I can't find any variable that can get the value of the key in Angular documentation
scope.$watch('$index',function(v){
    // do something here using the id of the image
    $('#target_photo_' + v)
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do? Good chance you don't need jQuery for whatever it is

Comment: @charlietfl : I need to bind a plugin called DarkRoomjs on every image instance which only accept image ID, that is the reason I need to add scope.$watch on every loop and get the ID of the image

Comment: Why You just dnt use cycle in controller? Something like: `for(var i = 0; i < $scope.moderation.contents.length; i++){//do something with i, content[i].reference etc}`;

Comment: @user3335966 : 
This is a sample id "target_photo_64c477aadb5cf74d5c8db95caa47e27858fa48b2". I cannot just create a running number. 

Aside from that,  user can get another set of records without refreshing the page. Something similar like facebook where it gets another set of records once it reached the bottom of the page.